How Can I Configure My MX Master 3 Mouse's Side Thumb Wheel to Control Volume on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I'm using an MX Master 3 mouse and want to configure the side thumb wheel to control the volume on Ubuntu. Specifically, I want the wheel to increase the volume when scrolled up and decrease it when scrolled down. Could you provide a detailed, step-by-step guide for this setup, including any necessary software installations and configuration steps? Thank you!
Tried this solution : How can I configure my mouse side buttons to control volume?Ubuntu 16.04
but it did not work on my pc.

Have you tried the Solaar app? sudo apt install solaar I can't say everything you can configure for the MX Master 3 but I can manage a lot of stuff for my k380 keyboard and M270 moue.
